# how to set the UIFont family and name with display font on the UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, fonts

I tried this code and crashed it says unwrapped it. so how I can show font with display and name on left cells.

result code:

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

let names = UIFont.familyNames.sorted()


@IBOutlet weak var FontTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

then i add the code to set display font with name. then it was crash this one.

```
}

 extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    names.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cells = FontTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells")
    

    
    for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
      
        let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        
        cells?.textLabel?.text = ("Family: \(family)")
        
        cells?.detailTextLabel?.text = ("Family: \(names)")
    }
    
    
    return cells!
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are you going to show in a single row. In your code cellForRowAt, every single row will run the loop. I guess you should not use the loop, instead use the data source **names**. Also, fontNames is also an array of Strings. So, based on your requirement(1st one may be), assign to detailsLabel.

```
       let family = names[indexPath.row] 
        
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
        
        cells?.textLabel?.text = ("Family: \(family)")
        
        cells?.detailTextLabel?.text = ("Family: \(fontNames)")
```

Comment: perfect, but I need to display the font types on text label... I tried this one but font name has error cuz I need both small to enough to see it. 
        
        let family = names[indexPath.row]
                
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
                
                cells?.textLabel?.text = ("\(family)")
        cells?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: family, size: 10)
                
                cells?.detailTextLabel?.text = ("\(fontNames)")
        cells?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: fontNames, size: 10)

Comment: As I said fontNames is an array, you should pass only first element -  cells?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: fontNames.first!, size: 10)